# How to access included dot directory on linux?

Tags: linux

I have com.example.lottobuyproject directory on my system.

I have no idea about how to access this included dot directory..

Please let me know how..

Below is tried image.

[image]

Comment: Maybe that's a file and not a directory?

Comment: No. it's directory name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All file (and directory) names on Linux are case sensitive. Try:

```
cd com.example.LottoBuyProject
```

Comment: Oh. it's cool.
Your answer works well.
Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

Please cd into the parent directory of your dir. And use cd ./com.example.LottoBuyProject, Then you can access your folder. I've tried this, it works.

Comment: Or, you can't access this folder, I notice that you use the command window, can you try other terminal on windows platform? For example, Xshell or SecureCRT.  Maybe, your command window on windows cause this problem

Comment: Thanks for your interest.. :D
But helped by Greg's answer.

Comment: It's OK you solve your problem.